# How can i reduce my mongodb docker image Size

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Currently the docker image size is 75mb. My dockerfile:

```
FROM zzrot/alpine-node:latest

RUN \
apk add --no-cache mongodb && \
rm /usr/bin/mongoperf

VOLUME /data/db
EXPOSE 27017 28017 3000
```

Comment: What's the size goal? Why?

Comment: When I build the same image it is 142 MB

Comment: yes after build, the image size is 142mb. But when I am only building a mongodb image, it comes around 75 mb. The size goal for only mongodb image is 50 mb. I want to keep the image size small so that building image on top of it will have small size and it will consume less space and will run faster.